# Calling a JavaScript Function With Arguments That Are Decided Later

Tags: javascript

I want to store a pointer to a function and then call it later with some arguments, but I'm having trouble with how to pass the arguments to the function.

For example:

```
var MyObject = (function () {
    return {
        myMethod: function (a, b) {
            return a + b;
        }
    };
}());

var method = MyObject.myMethod;
var args = [2, 5];

method(args);
```

So in the last line, which I know doesn't do what I want `method(args)`, I want to essentially call `MyObject.myMethod(2, 5)`, so my array attempt fails and creating an object also fails. How do I pass in the stored arguments to the stored method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) which accepts an array of arguments as an argument

```
var myarray = [2,5,...] //your array of arguments

method.apply(this,myarray);  //execute your method
```

and in the method you have, you can receive the arguments via the "hidden" "pseudo-array" `arguments` argument.

```
function method(){
   var args = arguments; //is [2,5,...]
}
```

this has advantage over [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) since you can pre-build the argument array and don't have to enumerate the arguments in the call's `()`

Answer (score 1):

K. Scott Allen has a great old article on this kind of thing.  Use `call` or `apply` as a way to affect the value of `this` inside the called function.

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the correct answer. Joseph just pipped you to the post.